# Using protractor to test link colours

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, protractor

How does one test the color of the link on hover using protractor?

I want to simulate the mouse hovering over a link, that link changes from say white to blue and then I want the test to expect that the color = blue, on hover.

code that I am currently using to test.

```
it('should redirect to the home page', function(){      
    element(by.css('ul.first_menu > li > a'));
    expect('ul.first_menu. > li > a'.getCssValue("color")).toEqual("rgba(11, 51, 60, 1)");

    browser.actions().mouseMove('ul.first_menu. > li > a').perform();

    browser.wait(waitForCssValue('ul.first_menu. > li > a', "color", "rgba(42, 100, 150, 1)"), 1000);
    browser.wait(waitForCssValue('ul.first_menu. > li > a', "text-decoration", "underline"), 1000);

    waitForCssValue = function (elementFinder, cssProperty, cssValue) {
            return function () {
                return elementFinder.getCssValue(cssProperty).then(function(actualValue) {
                return actualValue === cssValue;
                });
            };
    };
});
```

Comment: The **entire** web...must have taken years!

Comment: @Paulie_D if you ain't gonna help, then don't comment. It was an exaggeration to inform the reader I have done a lot of searching and I simply cannot find the solution to my problem so I have come here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done exactly what you are asking about.

The idea is to use [`getCssValue()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue) and get `color` and `text-decoration` properties. Then, hover the link with [`mouseMove()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) and *wait for CSS values to change*:

```
var elm = element(by.css('ul.first_menu > li > a'));
function waitForCssValue (elementFinder, cssProperty, cssValue) {
    return function () {
        return elementFinder.getCssValue(cssProperty).then(function(actualValue) {
            return actualValue === cssValue;
        });
    };
};

expect(elm.getCssValue("color")).toEqual("rgba(11, 51, 60, 1)");
expect(elm.getCssValue("text-decoration")).toEqual("none");

browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();

browser.wait(waitForCssValue(elm, "color", "rgba(42, 100, 150, 1)"), 1000);
browser.wait(waitForCssValue(elm, "text-decoration", "underline"), 1000);
```

Comment: hi, thanks. this looks very good. couple of questions 1) When you say `scope.page.link` is my element: what does this mean? my element is `'ul.firstmen > li > a '`..........................
also can this all go inside an it block?

Comment: @PeterJones `element(by.css('ul.firstmen > li > a'))` is an example of `scope.page.link`.

Comment: that's what i thought, cheers. will give this ago and then let you know results shortly!

Comment: Object ul.firstmen > li > a has no method 'getCssValue'?

Comment: @PeterJones are you making an element? Try exactly `element(by.css('ul.firstmen > li > a'))`.

Comment: posted exactly what I have in the question body, perhaps that will be clearer

Comment: @PeterJones okay, hope the updated answer makes things clearer. Also, if it solves the problem, consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: sure i will accept it. but not quite working yet. it says waitForCssValue is not defined. is my ordering correct? i think it is the same as yours...

Comment: @PeterJones see how `waitForCssValue()` is defined.

Comment: yeh it's not defined anywhere is it?! i tried to put a var in front of it. but it did not enjoy that.

Comment: thanks that is working now. it is doing some weird error though when i run just one expect statement, it says 2 test, 2 failures. the first one is failing because it is not equalling the correct colour, that is an easy fix. the second errorr is saying wait timed out after 1004ms, what is this?

Comment: @PeterJones `waitForCssValue` would just wait for a specific CSS property to be set on the element. If it is timeouted, you'll get the timeout error. I think, you can try getting rid of `waitForCssValue()` and just use `getCssValue()` as in the first part of the code.

Comment: having another slight issue at the moment. currently it is passing when I expect this
`expect(elm.getCssValue("color")).toEqual("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");`
the colour of the text is white but when hovered over it becomes an olive green colour. I suspect this is matching white to white? how do i put in a delay so it waits for the hover before doing the expect?

Comment: dont worry, just switched 2 statements around and it works!

Comment: Note I thought the inner function was excessive, but it's necessary to re-create the Promise (otherwise, the initially resolved Promise , **whose resolved state cannot change after any amount of time**, will be used... using a function to re-create a Promise gives a chance for the condition to change and result in a new resolved state!)